# regex match is catching the last but one character

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've the below text content

```
@@
ABCDEF ABCEDF sdfddg.
ABCDF ADVDDE
```

Here I'm trying to replace the line break with &&& in Notepad++. and when I'm using the below regex. 
    \r\n[^@@]
Here my condition is, if the line starts with `@@`, it should not be touched. when I try this, and replace in the replaced string, the first letter of all the lines are being replaced. currently it shows as

```
@@&&&BCDEF ABCEDF sdfddg.&&&BCDF ADVDDE
```

But I want it as

```
@@&&&ABCDEF ABCEDF sdfddg.&&&ABCDF ADVDDE
```

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern hardcodes a line break as CRLF, but there may be just LF or CR endings. Also, `[^@@]` matches any 1 char other than `@`, and is equal to `[^@]`.

You may use

```
\R(?!@@)
```

and replace with `&&&`.

**Details**

- `\R` - matches any line break (sequence) that is...
- `(?!@@)` - not followed with `@@` substring.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this explanation Sir :)